# SWIG issue, empty files being generated

Tags: java, java-native-interface, swig

I am trying to wrap a C++ class using SWIG to create a Java interface, but when I run SWIG on my files it generates empty files.

I am following the example found here: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/swig/swig-4/swig/Examples/java/class/index.html?txt

I have a header file like this:

```
#include <list>
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include <Heap.h>
#include "Controller.h"
namespace Arbitrator
{
  template <class _Tp,class _Val>
  class Arbitrator
  {
  public:
    Arbitrator();
    bool setBid(Controller<_Tp,_Val>* c, _Tp obj, _Val bid);
    bool setBid(Controller<_Tp,_Val>* c, std::set<_Tp> objs, _Val bid);
    bool removeBid(Controller<_Tp,_Val>* c, _Tp obj);
    bool removeBid(Controller<_Tp,_Val>* c, std::set<_Tp> objs);
    bool removeAllBids(Controller<_Tp,_Val>* c);
    bool accept(Controller<_Tp,_Val>* c, _Tp obj, _Val bid);
    bool accept(Controller<_Tp,_Val>* c, std::set<_Tp> objs, _Val bid);
    bool accept(Controller<_Tp,_Val>* c, _Tp obj);
    bool accept(Controller<_Tp,_Val>* c, std::set<_Tp> objs);
    bool decline(Controller<_Tp,_Val>* c, _Tp obj, _Val bid);
    bool decline(Controller<_Tp,_Val>* c, std::set<_Tp> objs, _Val bid);
    bool hasBid(_Tp obj) const;
    const std::pair<Controller<_Tp,_Val>*, _Val>& getHighestBidder(_Tp obj) const;
    const std::list< std::pair<Controller<_Tp,_Val>*, _Val> > getAllBidders(_Tp obj) const;
    const std::set<_Tp>& getObjects(Controller<_Tp,_Val>* c) const;
    void onRemoveObject(_Tp obj);
    _Val getBid(Controller<_Tp,_Val>* c, _Tp obj) const;
    void update();
  private:
    std::map<_Tp,Heap<Controller<_Tp,_Val>*, _Val> > bids;
    std::map<_Tp,Controller<_Tp,_Val>* > owner;
    std::map<Controller<_Tp,_Val>*, std::set<_Tp> > objects;
    std::set<_Tp> updatedObjects;
    std::set<_Tp> objectsCanIncreaseBid;
    std::set<_Tp> unansweredObjected;
    bool inUpdate;
    bool inOnOffer;
    bool inOnRevoke;
  };

  template <class _Tp,class _Val>
  Arbitrator<_Tp,_Val>::Arbitrator()
  {
    inUpdate=false;
    inOnOffer=false;
    inOnRevoke=false;
  }

  //other code removed to save space
```

And an interface file I created that looks like this:

```
/* arb.i */
%module arb
%{
#include "Arbitrator.h"
%}

/* grab header file */
%include "Arbitrator.h"
```

But when I run SWIG:

```
swig -c++ -java arb.i
```

The Java files that SWIG creates are empty.

Has anyone had this issue/know how to resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to explicitly instruct SWIG to generate code for the template, with the %template directive.

From the [SWIG 2.0 documentation on templates](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Allegrocl_nn26):

> SWIG provides support for dealing with templates, but by default, it
>   will not generate any member variable or function wrappers for
>   templated classes. In order to create these wrappers, you need to
>   explicitly tell SWIG to instantiate them. This is done via the
>   %template directive.

Some simple examples from the [SWIG 2.0 Templates chapter](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#SWIGPlus_nn30):

```
/* Instantiate a few different versions of the template */
%template(intList) List<int>;
%template(doubleList) List<double>;
```